# TypeScript Error with migrating Umzug to v3: 'umzug.on' not recognized

Tags: node.js, typescript, eventemitter, umzug

I'm working with the Umzug library for database migration in a TypeScript project and encountering an issue when trying to use the on method with an Umzug instance. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```js
export async function connectUmzug(dbConfig) {
  return new Umzug({...});
}
```

Usage:

```js
const umzug = await connectUmzug(config);
umzug.on('migrating', logUmzugEvent('migrating'));
```

I get the following error:

```
Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Umzug<any>'
```

In the type definition, it states:

```js
class Umzug<Ctx extends object = object> extends emittery<UmzugEvents<Ctx>>
```

Why is the `on` method not recognized in this context?